# Time out when trying to connect to AWS DocumentDB from local NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose, aws-documentdb

I am trying to connect to DynamoDB from my local NodeJS app. My configuration is as follows:

**`connect-database.js`**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require("path")

const connectDatabase = (mongoDbUrl) => {
    mongoose.connect(mongoDbUrl, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        ssl: true,
        sslValidate: false,
        sslCA: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../config/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem'))
    })
}
```

**`index.js`**

```
connectDatabase('mongodb://<username>:<password>@<connection-string>/?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false')
```

I felt it had something to do with security group inbound rules so I have added it to allow inbound from all protocols and all ports on my security group but it still won't work. It's even more confusing since I am able to connect to it from my AWS Cloud9 instance.

The error I get is **MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND**. It means it is unable to connect to the database at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, there is no way to open access to documentsdb cluster from outside, except through ssh tunnel. See [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-from-outside-a-vpc.html).

Comment: Thank you! Marked you as the answer. :)